# How to save Amazon Redshift output to local csv through SQL Developer

Tags: csv, automation, export, amazon-redshift, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am trying save Amazon Redshift output to local csv through SQL Developer.  Please suggest a solution other than the export wizard in SQL Developer to generate csv, as the data volume is in 10s of millions and the extract is required frequently. Spool command is creating file in local but unable to format it as a CSV file.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "sql developer" ? I do this often using my development IDE (Datagrip) but I am not familiar with your ide if it is called "sql developer".

Comment: I assume by the direct nature of the question that UNLOADing to S3 and then slurping that data in is not an option.  If this is not correct please say so and solution in that space will be provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason we support redshift's JDBC driver in SQL Developer is so you can migrate that data warehouse to Oracle Autonomous DW Cloud Service.

Yes, you can run queries and spool CSV to local files, and that might be faster than using the wizard, but what you're describing isn't really what ORACLE SQL Developer is built for.

Comment: Thank you for answering. But I am unable generate a proper CSV file, I tried as below,colsep and trimspool is not working. Please help.  set colsep ','
set echo off
set linesize 1000
set pagesize 0
set sqlprompt ''
set trimspool on
set headsep on
spool 'C:\ThePath\file_name.csv';
select * from schema.view_name;
spool off;

Comment: Select /*csv*/ * from table

Comment: This is working for me. Please suggest how to handle these 3  issues inside spool script. 1., how to remove the double quote enclosing the values in CSV file export.  2., How to add the EOL character in Linux(LF) format , currently it EOL is in windows format. 3., How to remove the row number written at the end of the CSV file.   Notepad++ was not effective to handle these issues as the file size was high.

Comment: Why not follow advice and use a different tool? There are plenty of good IDEs for Redshift that will allow CSVs to be exported. Try this one. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/connecting-using-workbench.html

Comment: there are ways to remove the quotes and the number of rows included in the feedback, there are SET commands to control this behavior

Comment: I have tried set heading off and set feedback off, but this command is not working for redshift DB in Oracle SQL Developer. Also I have tried select col1||','||col2 from viewname; this removed the double quote but I got null values printed for multiple values. Please suggest the solution to remove the number of rows and feedback from CSV.

Comment: stop trying to use sqldev as a database GUI for any database, it's built for Oracle